# panoramic text visualization with seadragon (or other)?

Tags: text, visualization

i'm working on a visualization of a text file with 100k lines, max 1k characters/line, as one large, navigable image.

similar to the bleak house example in blaise's ted talk demo of seadragon, but even simpler -- basically just the view from `cat filename.txt`, but with a view that's zoomed out so that the whole file is initially visible (each line fitting on the page width, *without wordwrap*) and can then be zoomed in on.

is this currently possible with seadragon? if not, any ideas on how i can attempt it?

(oh, and including hyperlinks would be great -- but i don't expect that'll be possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you'll be able to go up to 100k lines but the [OpenZoom SDK](http://openzoom.org/) with the Flash Text Engine could get you pretty far.

**Example**
http://gasi.ch/go/openzoom-fte/

**Source Code**
http://github.com/openzoom/sdk/raw/be50b3f1062e68d88dcf20f412e6fdb9b7320ed3/examples/flex/flash-text-engine/src/FlashTextEngine.mxml

Answer (score 0):

A second vote for the answer to this question... I'd like to use seadragon or other technology to achieve a similar effect.